# Using mask in richfaces

Tags: jquery

I'm using richfaces 3 and trying to create a mask, like this:

```
<rich:jQuery selector=".mymask" query="setMask({mask:'99.999'})" />
```

In my field inputted the following:

```
<h:inputText styleClass="mymask" value="#{bean.value}">                                         
</h:inputText>
```

I have 2 problems with this:

1) The mask just work if I type something in field. When this field is loaded in browser the mask is not applied yet.

2) When the value is submitted the "dots" are sent together. I need ignore the dots. Here, Number `33.412` should send `33412` to BackingBean.

Comment: Maybe you should mention the fact that you're using a jQuery plugin, this isn't really a problem with JSF or RF.

Comment: really, i already change the tags in my post to jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think it works as intended. So if you want to add something to this, then you should do it by yourself. You can e.g. add placeholder:

   ```
   <rich:jQuery selector=".mymask" query="attr('placeholder', '99.999')" />
   ```
2. There's also no magic here. JSF doesn't know that you are using some mask. I know two ways of resolving that:

   1. You should parse your input as it is (with mask) or use converter.
   2. Just unmasked inputs before submitting the value e.g.:

      ```
      <a4j:commandLink onclick="$('.mymask').inputmask('remove')"
          <!-- other stuff (save or other action) --> 
      </a4j:commandLink>
      ```

Comment: Glad I could help :)